# Show that the statistic $T(X)$ is complete.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

**Exercise:** Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a sample from the distribution with density $$f(x|\theta) = \dfrac{2x}{\theta^2}\mathbb{1}_{(0,\theta)}(x)$$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

Show that the statistic $T(X) = \max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is complete.

*What I've tried:* I know that a statistic $T$ is said to be complete for $\theta\in\Omega$ if for any Borel function $f$, $\operatorname{E}_\theta f(T) = 0$ for all $P_\theta \in \Omega$, implies that $f(T)=0$, $P_\theta$-a.s. for all $\theta$. So what I want to do is take $\operatorname{E}_\theta f(T)$ and show that this is only equal to zero when $f(T) = 0$. If I'm correct, that means that I need to show that $$\displaystyle\int f(T(X))\dfrac{2x}{\theta^2}\mathbb{1}_{(0,\theta)}(x)dx = 0$$ implies $f(T(X)) = 0$. I'm not sure how to proceed from here though.

**Question:** How do I solve this exercise?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$As is already derived in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2610522/302797), the density function of $T$ is$$
f_T(t; θ) = \frac{2n}{θ^{2n}} t^{2n - 1} I_{(0, θ)}(t),
$$
thus for any Borel function $g$,$$
E_θ(g(T)) = \int_0^θ g(t) \cdot \frac{2n}{θ^{2n}} t^{2n - 1} \,\d t = \frac{2n}{θ^{2n}} \int_0^θ g(t) t^{2n - 1} \,\d t. \tag{1}
$$

If Borel function $g$ satisfies that$$
E_θ(g(T)) = 0, \quad \forall θ \in {\mit Θ} = (0, +\infty)
$$
then by (1) there is$$
\int_0^θ g(t) t^{2n - 1} \,\d t = 0, \quad \forall θ > 0
$$
which implies for any interval $(a, b) \subseteq  (0, +\infty)$,$$
\int_a^b g(t) t^{2n - 1}\,\d t = 0.
$$
Therefore, $g(t) t^{2n - 1}$ equals $0$ a.e. on $(0, +\infty)$,  so $g(t)$ equals $0$ a.e. on $(0, +\infty)$. Thus for any $θ > 0$,$$
P_θ(g(T) = 0) = \int_0^θ I_{\{t' \mid g(t') = 0\}}(t) \cdot \frac{2n}{θ^{2n}} t^{2n - 1} \,\d t = \int_0^θ \frac{2n}{θ^{2n}} t^{2n - 1} \,\d t = 1.
$$
Hence $T$ is complete.

Comment: If ${\mit Θ} = (0, c)$, the above deduction still applies, but with minor modification.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I don't understand the relation between a.e. and a.s. though. They want me to show that $\operatorname{E}_\theta(f(T)) = 0$ for all $\theta\in\Omega$, implies that $f(T) =0$, $P_\theta$ for all $\theta$. How does this follow from your answer? Perhaps I don't understand correctly what $P_\theta$ a.s. means.

Comment: In this particular question, $T$ has a density functiin, thus it suffices to prove $g(t) = 0$ holds a.e.